# Displaying aggregate data per hour

Tags: mysql, datetime, group-by, hour

I have a MySQL database with a table containing timestamped logins and I would like to get the number of logins for each hour of the last 24 hours.

At first, I tried something obvious:

```
SELECT
  timestamp AS Hour,
  COUNT(*) AS Logins
FROM auth
WHERE
  timestamp >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY HOUR(timestamp)
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

This results in output similar to the following:

```
+---------------------+--------+
| Hour                | Logins |
+---------------------+--------+
| 2017-10-08 17:00:05 |    272 |
| 2017-10-08 16:00:02 |    323 |
| 2017-10-08 15:00:34 |    301 |
| 2017-10-08 14:55:10 |     30 |
| 2017-10-08 11:04:27 |    107 |
| 2017-10-08 10:06:26 |    115 |
| 2017-10-08 09:00:11 |     92 |
| 2017-10-08 08:02:34 |    195 |
| 2017-10-08 07:03:15 |    171 |
| 2017-10-08 06:03:06 |    133 |
| 2017-10-08 05:00:20 |    102 |
| 2017-10-08 04:03:23 |    198 |
| 2017-10-08 03:00:23 |    345 |
| 2017-10-08 02:01:39 |    318 |
| 2017-10-08 01:01:22 |    205 |
| 2017-10-08 00:00:24 |    334 |
| 2017-10-07 23:00:00 |    501 |
| 2017-10-07 22:00:10 |    377 |
| 2017-10-07 21:00:02 |    482 |
| 2017-10-07 20:00:04 |    349 |
| 2017-10-07 19:00:54 |    298 |
| 2017-10-07 18:13:06 |    438 |
+---------------------+--------+
22 rows in set (0,02 sec)
```

There are two problems with this output. The first one is that the timestamps are not at the whole hour, because the first login occurred a few minutes/seconds after the exact hour. Also, I don't really need the date in the output. I have fixed this problem by doing the following:

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(timestamp, INTERVAL 30 MINUTE),'%H:00:00') AS Hour,
  COUNT(*) AS Logins
FROM auth
WHERE
  timestamp >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY HOUR(timestamp)
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

and the output now is

```
+----------+--------+
| Hour     | Logins |
+----------+--------+
| 17:00:00 |    272 |
| 16:00:00 |    323 |
| 15:00:00 |    301 |
| 15:00:00 |     30 |
| 11:00:00 |    107 |
| 10:00:00 |    115 |
| 09:00:00 |     92 |
| 08:00:00 |    195 |
| 07:00:00 |    171 |
| 06:00:00 |    133 |
| 05:00:00 |    102 |
| 04:00:00 |    198 |
| 03:00:00 |    345 |
| 02:00:00 |    318 |
| 01:00:00 |    205 |
| 00:00:00 |    334 |
| 23:00:00 |    501 |
| 22:00:00 |    377 |
| 21:00:00 |    482 |
| 20:00:00 |    349 |
| 19:00:00 |    298 |
| 18:00:00 |    452 |
+----------+--------+
22 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

**Question #1**: Is this a good way of doing this (displaying the whole hour) or is there a better one?

The second problem I don't know how to solve. You see, the above command was executed at 18:19 local time. Note that the number of logins between 18:00 and 18:19 is missing. Yes, I understand that the last whole hour has not ended yet, but still, I would like to display the data that has been accumulated during the part of it that has elapsed.

**Question #2**: How to do this?

Comment: I tend to think it bad practice to GROUP BY anything other than the thing you're selecting. Display issues should be handled in application code

Comment: @Strawberry, not sure what you mean. I select and group by `timestamp`. Do you mean that I should use `HOUR(DATE_ADD(timestamp, INTERVAL 30 MINUTE))` instead of `DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(timestamp, INTERVAL 30 MINUTE),'%H:00:00')`? Fine, whatever, but problem #2 isn't solved by this.

Comment: Why are you adding 30 minutes to ``timestamp``?

Comment: @kmoser, You're right, it's not necessary; just `HOUR(timestamp)` would do. It's a leftover from when I was trying to convert the timestamp to a whole hour. But removing it doesn't fix the problem of the missing last (incomplete) hour of data.

Comment: @bontchev In your original post you wrote "Note that the number of logins between 18:00 and 18:19 is missing". This is incorrect. The row for 18:00 sums all the logins between 18:00 and 18:59:59. If you run the query at 18:19, it will include the logins from 18:00 to 18:19 (i.e. the current time).

Comment: @kmoser, Yes, you are right. The problem is in the grouping. It groups the data from the last hour with the data for the first hour of the 24-hour period. I've figured out how to solve it; I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @kmoser pointed out, the problem comes from the fact that the data for the last (incomplete) hour of the 24-hour period is grouped with the first hour of it - because the hour number is the same. In order to solve this, we need to group by something that differentiates between the same hours of different days. Here is the solution that worked for me:

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') AS Hour,
  COUNT(*) AS Logins
FROM auth
WHERE
  timestamp >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) as cnt
from  auth
where date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
```

Comment: This answer is horribly, utterly wrong. Did you even understand the question?